# session is empty even i set values

Tags: php, session, session-variables

First I'm setting sessions, but when I `print_r()` the `$_SESSION` it only shows `Array() 1`

I did start the session on both files doing `session_start()`;

Function I'm using:

```
function login($Username, $password, $pdo)
{


    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `klanten` WHERE Inlognaam='$Username'");
    $sth->execute();


if ($sth->rowCount() == 1)  // als er een row is met die username dan gaat hij verder
{

    // Variabelen inlezen uit query
    $row = $sth->fetch();
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $row['Salt']); // encrypt het wachtwoord

    if ($row['Paswoord'] == $password) // als het wachtwoord gelijk is aan het ingevulde wachtwoord
    {

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //  kijken welke browser je gebruikt

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['KlantID'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Inlognaam'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $row['Level'];
        $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',$password . $user_browser);

        // Login successful.
        return true;
     } 
     else 
     {
        // password incorrect
        return false;
     }
}
else
{
    // username bestaat niet
    return false;
}
}
```

Page 2

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION) . '</pre>';
```

Which returns only `Array()`

Comment: Do you have `session_start` function in both files?

Comment: Yes, i do. This is not the case

Comment: Then provided code is not enough.

Comment: As stated in the info "I have started the session before doing anything"

Comment: provide complete code for both file/page ?

Comment: Saved the full code for the function.

Comment: I have doubt here `if ($row['Paswoord'] == $password)` are you sure you are getting return `true` ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, there's one odd thing too. If the function returns true i'm echo'ing out all the sessions too, but when it gets back to the home page it doesnt seem like it held all the sessions

Comment: Do you think it could be because i'm running this on a xampp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**You might have not started the session.This worked for me**
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['KlantID'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Inlognaam'];
    $_SESSION['level'] = $row['Level'];
    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',$password . $user_browser);

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION,true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: As said before, i have started the session

Comment: You might have started the session in another file...First include that file ...........

Comment: This is not a full php file. This is only a function i'm using

Comment: $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `klanten` WHERE Inlognaam='$Username'");

Comment: You are validating only usename in the database...There might be several user with the same name..Please check your database table and rows....

Comment: if($sth->rowCount() == 1) fails if there are many users with the name.....

Answer (score 1):

Second param in method `print_r` is to return not to print, to get print use like this,

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION) . '</pre>';
```

Get more detail from here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: This returned Array ( ) 1, nothing else